# Multiple Face Flip Cards with CSS and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, flipview

I need some help creating multiple instances if a flip card (with multiple faces) on one page.

I can perfectly create one instance of the multi-face flip card thanks to the [fiddle by Matt Coughlin](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/MXv4f/7/)

The problem is when I want to create a second and third flip card on the same page.

In the code snippet below, the buttons on the left control both flip cards.
Also, the content of the first flip card is displayed on both sides.

I suppose I can create a function and complete different classes for each instance, but I'm hoping there is a less code-intensive approach.

Thank you

```js
var topCard = 1;
var facingUp = true;

function flipCard(n) {
    if (topCard === n) return;

    // Replace the contents of the current back-face with the contents
    // of the element that should rotate into view.
    var curBackFace = $('.' + (facingUp ? 'face2' : 'face1'));
    var nextContent = $('.store' + n).html(); 
    var nextContent = $('.store li:nth-child(' + n + ')').html(); 
    curBackFace.html(nextContent);

    // Rotate the content
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    topCard = n;
    facingUp = !facingUp;
}

$('#flip1').on('click', function(){ flipCard(1); });
$('#flip2').on('click', function(){ flipCard(2); });
$('#flip3').on('click', function(){ flipCard(3); });
$('#flip4').on('click', function(){ flipCard(4); });

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add the appropriate content to the initial "front side"
    var frontFace = $('.face1');
    var frontContent = $('.store li:first-child').html(); 
    frontFace.html(frontContent);
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3em;
  
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    margin: 0 auto 40px auto;

    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
       -moz-perspective: 800px;
        -ms-perspective: 800px;
         -o-perspective: 800px;
            perspective: 800px;
}
.container .card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 1s;
        -ms-transition:     -ms-transform 1s;
         -o-transition:      -o-transform 1s;
            transition:         transform 1s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.container .card .face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 140px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
         -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container .card.flipped,
.container .card .face2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
         -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.container .card .face .content1 {background-color: #7ad;}
.container .card .face .content2 {background-color: #7da;}
.container .card .face .content3 {background-color: #d7a;}
.container .card .face .content4 {background-color: #fad997;}

.store {
    display: none;
}
.buttons {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">

  <div class="box">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face face1"></div>
        <div class="face face2"></div>
    </div>

    <ul class="store">
        <li>
            <div class="content content1">1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content2">2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content3">3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content4">4</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" id="flip1" value="Flip 1"/>
    <input type="button" id="flip2" value="Flip 2"/>
    <input type="button" id="flip3" value="Flip 3"/>
    <input type="button" id="flip4" value="Flip 4"/>
</div>

 
</div>
  
  
    <div class="box">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face face1"></div>
        <div class="face face2"></div>
    </div>

    <ul class="store">
        <li>
            <div class="content content1">11</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content2">12</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content3">13</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content content4">14</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <input type="button" id="flip11" value="Flip 11"/>
    <input type="button" id="flip12" value="Flip 12"/>
    <input type="button" id="flip13" value="Flip 13"/>
    <input type="button" id="flip14" value="Flip 14"/>
</div>

 
</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your script a bit, but it should work now as you want.

main problem was that when your clicked on a button it didn't knew what card to flip.

**Demo**

```js
function flipCard(n, obj, i) {
  var topCard = obj.attr("data-topCard") || 1;
  var facingUp = obj.attr("data-facingUp") || true;
  if (topCard === n) return;

  // Replace the contents of the current back-face with the contents
  // of the element that should rotate into view.
  var curBackFace = obj.find('.' + (facingUp ? 'face2' : 'face1'));
  var nextContent = obj.find('.store li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').html();
  curBackFace.html(nextContent);

  // Rotate the content
  obj.find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  obj.attr("data-topCard", n)
  obj.attr("data-facingUp", !facingUp)
}

$('.flip').on('click', function() {
  flipCard($(this).val(), $(this).closest(".box"), $(this).index());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the appropriate content to the initial "front side"
  $(".box").each(function() {
    var frontFace = $(this).find('.face1');
    var frontContent = $(this).find('.store li:first-child').html();
    frontFace.html(frontContent);
  });
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3em;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -ms-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.container .card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container .card .face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 140px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container .card.flipped,
.container .card .face2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.container .card .face .content1 {
  background-color: #7ad;
}

.container .card .face .content2 {
  background-color: #7da;
}

.container .card .face .content3 {
  background-color: #d7a;
}

.container .card .face .content4 {
  background-color: #fad997;
}

.store {
  display: none;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">

  <div class="box">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="face face1"></div>
        <div class="face face2"></div>
      </div>

      <ul class="store">
        <li>
          <div class="content content1">1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="content content2">2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="content content3">3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="content content4">4</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="button" class="flip" value="1" />
      <input type="button" class="flip" value="2" />
      <input type="button" class="flip" value="3" />
      <input type="button" class="flip" value="4" />
    </div>


  </div>


  <div class="box">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="face face1"></div>
        <div class="face face2"></div>
      </div>

      <ul class="store">
        <li>
          <div class="content content1">11</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="content content2">12</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="content content3">13</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="content content4">14</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="button" class="flip" value="11" />
      <input type="button" class="flip" value="12" />
      <input type="button" class="flip" value="13" />
      <input type="button" class="flip" value="14" />
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. There seems to be a bit of an issue though. It seems that every second click, irrespective of which button, simply return the value of 1 and not the correct content.